# How to analyze Typescript project with SonarQube Scanner on Jenkins' Mac OS slave?

Tags: typescript, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I try to analyze a TypeScript project in Jenkins with SonarQube Scanner plug-in on a Mac OS slave.

**Tools:**

- Jenkins (version 2.32.1)
- [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) plug-in (version 2.5)
- [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) (version 2.8)
- [SSH slave](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin) plug-in (version 1.12)
- SonarQube (version 6.7)
- [SonarTS](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarts.html) (version 1.1)
- Mac OS X (version 10.12.6)

**Problem:**

SonarTS plug-in tries to start [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), but Node.js is not in the `PATH` variable, see log:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.sonar.plugin.typescript.ExternalTypescriptSensor.executeExternalRunner(ExternalTypescriptSensor.java:175)
```

**Research:**

I tried to configure the path on Mac with:

- `environment.plist` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313578/5277820)

  but it doesn't work, because it is not supported anymore.
- `/etc/launchd.conf` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257454/5277820)

  but it doesn't work, because it is not supported anymore.
- `/etc/paths.d/` (from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106549)

  but it doesn't work (same error message).

I tried to use the already added paths (`/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin`) with:

- symbolic link

  but it doesn't work, because the paths are write-protected (even for administrator).

I tried to pass the path to the SonarQube Scanner:

- JVM option (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21094766/5277820)

  but it doesn't work (same error message).

I also read about changing path in the calling source:

- [`ProcessBuilder#environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--) (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155791/5277820)

  but I didn't try it, because I don't want to patch the SonarQube Scanner source (for maintenance reasons).
- `ProcessStarter#setGlobalSearchPath` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206961/5277820)

  but I didn't try it, because I don't want to patch the SonarQube Scanner source (for maintenance reasons).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SonarTS 1.2 or later, you could instead try to specify the path to the nodejs executable in the settings using SonarQube UI:

[image]

Comment: That would be a solution, but at the moment we are only using LTS versions (company policy). With the next released LTS version, I will update and use it.

Comment: You can continue using SonarQube 6.7 LTS, but update just the SonarTS plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [Environment Injector Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject) (version 2.1.5):

> **Summary**
>
> EnvInject plugin provides the following features:
>
> - Removes inherited environment variables by the Jenkins Java process
> - Injects environment variables at node (master/slave) startup
> - Executes a setup script before or/and after a SCM checkout for a run
> - Injects environment variables before or/and after a SCM checkout for a run
> - Injects environment variables as a build step for a run
> - Injects password values for a run
> - Exports environment variables at the end of the build in order to to know the set of environment variables used for each build

So it is possible to add Node.js' path to the `PATH` variable:

[image]